# Issue with Keras using pretrained Inceptionv3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using InceptionV3 with imagenet weights in Keras. The version of Keras I am using is 2.2.4 and Keras-applications is 1.0.8. The tensorflow version is 1.14.0. I am following the standard way of using InceptionV3 for transfer learning, as outlined [here](https://keras.io/applications/). I am getting this error `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer global_average_pooling2d_3: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2`. I found a GitHub [post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/issues/45) where the user was facing the same issue. I followed the suggestion which fixed the issue on the GitHub post, but I have had no such luck. MWE is below

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top='False')

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) # Error appears here
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Comment: you are probably not feeding the network with images. check if images are read

Comment: @IoannisNasios While that is a possible source of errors, in this case the problem arises when applying the pooling layer, signalling a dimensionality mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you passed the *string* `'False'` to `include_top`. Non-empty strings evaluate to `True`, so what you thought was the topless model was, in fact, fully adorned with the dimensionality-reducing average pooling and fully-connected layers.

Accordingly, one way to solve your problem would be to change `'False'` to `False`. I would add, however, that you can just specify `pooling='avg'`, so you only have to add the last `Dense` layer...