# Problem With Keras InceptionV3 Weights ? Issue about Using Pre-Trained Model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

This is more of an 'issue' rather than a question but, I noticed something today while trying some transfer learning using Keras. I found that the InceptionV3 model and pre-trained weights on [Francois Chollet's repository](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/tag/v0.2) are different from the [Kaggle one](https://www.kaggle.com/madmaxliu/inceptionv3). I checked that using the `diff` command. 
Not only that, when I use the code block as below--

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

Inception_pretrained_weight = '../pre_weight/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_chollet.h5'

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=(160, 160, 3), 
                           include_top=False, 
                           weights=Inception_pretrained_weight)

for lr in pre_trained_model.layers:
    lr.trainable = False


for layr in pre_trained_model.layers:
    print("layer names: ", layr.name)
```

I get an error as--

```
ValueError: Layer #0 (named "conv2d_753" in the current model) was found to correspond to layer convolution2d_1 in the save file. However the new layer conv2d_753 expects 1 weights, but the saved weights have 2 elements.
```

This does not happen with the model available on the Kaggle page. Have anyone noticed this yet? Does anyone know how and why these models differ ? I found another post on this-[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752829/issue-with-keras-using-pretrained-inceptionv3), but it does not really help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: keras.applications has its own weights, it makes no sense to try to use other weights because as you see, they do not match with the model structure, so there is no actual issue here.

Comment: Thank you @MatiasValdenegro for your response. I am not sure whether the question was clear or not but, my point was Inception weights available [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/tag/v0.2) are different from the [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/madmaxliu/inceptionv3) one (same filename). What exactly you mean by _try to use other weights_? I understand that the models don't match. I thought these weights were obtained from training Inception network for Imagenet data, so my question was why and how they are different? Thanks!